# Why increasing Lasso alpha values the root mean squared error only increase?

Tags: scikit-learn, alpha, lasso-regression

Hi i am fitting a Lasso model using different values in the range of 2*10^-5 to 500 for the alpha parameters like:

```
alphas=np.linspace(0.00002,500,20)
```

when i plot the negative root mean squared error and absolute error from cross validation i get a graph like this:

[image: img1]

so the error increases in modulo and then stays constant instead of decreasing... why am i getting this result?

Choosing really small values of alpha like:

```
alphas=np.linspace(0.00001,0.00007,20)
```

i get this result for RMSE:

[image]

Do you have any idea why it seems to working only for so little values of alpha? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lasso regression aims to increase bias and decrease variance. By increasing penalty term you are moving away from the predictor that has the lowest bias (increasing RMSE). The estimator with the lowest RMSE is not always the best due to potential overfitting. Search for [bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff)

Comment: yes i have that clear, but in this case the graph is of the error i get from cross validation. error should decrease to a certain point and then increase again as it is doing for those extremely low alpha values... my doubt is if makes any sense to have alpha so little

Comment: yes I see your point. To have alphas so little means a simple linear regression is the best. In cases like this I would look at the data distribution again and try to explain it intuitively.